# H2 PARSEDATETIME cannot parse yyMMdd format text

Tags: h2

I'm trying to load some CSV data:

```
SELECT  
PARSEDATETIME('TS', 'yyMMdd') as V  
FROM CSVREAD('E:/sample-data/jmg.asc',   
'SYMBOL, TS, HIGH, LOW, OPENING, CLOSING, VOLUME', 'fieldSeparator=,');
```

My file has one row:

```
JMG,000105,148.0000,150.0000,147.5000,148.7500,351500
```

000105 is in YYMMDD format so the date should be 05 January 2000.

When I run the above SQL I get

```
SELECT  
PARSEDATETIME('TS', 'yyMMdd') as V  
FROM CSVREAD('E:/DEV/robotrader/micdev.robo.db/sample-data/jmg.asc',  
'SYMBOL, TS, HIGH, LOW, OPENING, CLOSING,VOLUME', 'fieldSeparator=,');  

Error parsing "TS"; SQL statement:  
SELECT 
PARSEDATETIME('TS', 'yyMMdd') as V 
FROM CSVREAD('E:/DEV/robotrader/micdev.robo.db/sample-data/jmg.asc', 
'SYMBOL, TS, HIGH, LOW, OPENING, CLOSING,VOLUME', 'fieldSeparator=,') 
[90014-172] 90014/90014 (Help)
```

'yyMMdd' should be fine for SimpleDateFormat.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

BTW, I'm in the UK, Windows 8 x64, H2 version 1.3.172. I've just started experimenting with H2 so am a bit of a newbie...
Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
PARSEDATETIME('TS', 'yyMMdd')
```

with

```
PARSEDATETIME(TS, 'yyMMdd')
```